# How to prevent breaklines inside \cvcomputer in moderncv

Tags: line-breaking, moderncv

I'm writing my CV in Latex using the package `moderncv` and I've realized that the default behavior of the `\cvcomputer` command is to insert automatic breaklines inside the text, making it about as long as half of the page's width.

Is there a way to prevent the command from inserting breaklines and make it use all the available page space?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\cvcomputer` is depreciated. It is an alias for `\cvdoubleitem`, which takes 4 arguments and is meant to create two columns with a label and text each.

If you want a single column with a label, use `\cvitem` instead. `\cvitem` takes 2 mandatory arguments: the label and the text.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there some official documentation explaining the new commands?

Comment: @user1301428 No, there is no official documentation (yet). There is however an [official template](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/examples/template.tex) that uses all the available commands and contains lots of comments.